# How do I make sure the length is 6 in this regular expression?

Tags: java, regex

I have this regular expression that I wrote, which extracts text in between tags like `"#<string to extract>"`:

```
"#<(.+?)>"
```

I need to make sure that the length of the string I'm extracting is 6 and my current solution is checking the length of the string that I extracted with an `if` statement. I would like to replace this with a regex instead. How could I modify `"#<(.+?)>"` to make sure it is 6 characters when extracted?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use curly braces to specify the length of the match.

```
#<(.{6})>
```